# Load favicon.ico by url is not working in spring boot,thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i wanted to set my favicon.ico by a url like this

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" th:href="${commonResponse.appTheme.iconImageUrl}">
```

when i inspect it showing the link like this

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://tb-merchant.apptizer.io/applova/app-images/21726_21540783/app-icon.png">
```

If i click the link image is loaded but the favicon ico is not showing.Any reason why?

Comment: Does your image meet the [requirements](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)?

Comment: it does meet the requirement.

Comment: I have loaded your image and used it as favicon, there are no problems with it, it displays fine. As I understand, you are not hosting this image, right? In this case, you should verify the security/CORS settings of your application to display external content from non-SSL sources.